# Program or browser extension to copy the text displayed in an HTML dropdown list

Tags: web

Question [posted](https://superuser.com/q/571753/116475) by  [Steve Chambers](https://superuser.com/users/194625/steve-chambers):

> There's a dropdown list on a webpage with numerous values in it. I simply want to copy these values into the Windows or Ubuntu clipboard and paste them into a text editor with one value per line.

Which program or browser extension allows the user to copy the text displayed in an HTML dropdown list?

---

- License: any
- Price: any
- Operating system: Windows or Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Solution using 2 programs:

1. In Google Chrome, select the object and hit "Inspect" which will tell you where the dropdown is in the code. Then, right-click on the "select" area that is the dropdown, and hit "copy as HTML". [step from [SU](https://superuser.com/a/571764/116475) by [killermist](https://superuser.com/users/139040/killermist)].

   Corresponding screenshots:
   [image]

[image]

2. Copy the HTML code on https://htmlcodeeditor.com/:

   [image]